# How to properly serve static assets using express.static on Heroku server?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, ejs

**Here's my file structure...**

[...root]/src/server.js

[...root]/src/public/images/some_type/some_image.png

[...root]/src/views/index.js (using EJS templating to render views... templating engine works fine)

**Here's the code...**

server.js:

`server.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`

index.js:

`<img src="../public/images/some_type/some_image.png">`

**I'm getting this error in browser:**

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Everything works fine in locally hosted dev environment. Breaks when pushed to Heroku server. Does anyone know why this could be?

Reading the documentation, I don't see why my setup wouldn't work...

*"...the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process."*

Isn't my node process launched from where the server is located (i.e. src/server.js)? Even if I did set this up "wrong", why would this work fine in dev and not hosted prod env?

I've tried many different combinations of changing the paths in both index.js path and server.js to no avail...

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: just wondering, can you try your source path like this: <img src="/public/images/some_type/some_image.png">

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It works perfectly fine locally, but when I re-deploy on heroku still the same issue. Resource not found.

Comment: one more suggestion then i'll shut up :) 
server.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')))

Comment: Still the same issue. I appreciate the suggestions though.